# Make ExoPlayer seek to last point in time whenever play is pressed from the notification?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

The application streams audio from a server using ExoPlayer, I have an issue of streaming clients falling behind when they pause and play again. I need for the stream to be caught up every time playing is resumed. All this from the notification controls.

I've got it working inside the app with `seekTo(0)` but apparently the notification control calls are different.

```
fun play() {
        player?.playWhenReady = true
        player?.seekTo(0)
}

fun pause() {
        player?.playWhenReady = false
}
```

Is there anywhere to access whatever the notification controls are calling and maybe modify them?

Answer (score 1):

I think `PlayerNotificationManager` class might help you,Once attached the manager will keep it sync with player so it might help in your case.

You can have a look at this blog it might help:
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/playback-notifications-with-exoplayer-a2f1a18cf93b

Comment: I already a PlayerNotificationManager implementation. It doesn't help with that I think because whatever the notification is calling I can't access (in other words I don't know what it's calling).

Comment: @Jax Well,for that i might have to take a good look at it,will post it if i find something useful.